# How to add frames in Python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

In the code given below, I want to open the file open dialog box only when the "soil" checkbutton is checked and repeat the same for "weather" checkbutton.

The "soil" Checkbutton, "weather" Checkbutton & the "Submit" button needs to be placed LEFT side of the frame of the GUI & The scrollbar should contain the details of the 2 opened files(the files selected from the "file open dialog box" which in the "text" format) which is to be placed in the RIGHT side of the frame  of the GUI

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

win = Tk()

frame = Frame(win)
frame.pack()

rightframe = Frame(win)
rightframe.pack( side = RIGHT )

#frame_name = Frame(win)
#frame_address = Frame(win)

win.title("Spatialization of DSSAT model")

w = 800
h = 400

ws = win.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = win.winfo_screenheight()

x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

win.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def forCheckbutton1():
    filename1 = askopenfilename()
    print(filename1)

def forCheckbutton2():
    filename2 = askopenfilename()
    print(filename2)

def forMuButton1():
    win.destroy()

def var_states():
    print("soil: %d, \nweather:%d" % (MyVar1.get(), MyVar2.get()))

MyLabel1 = Label(frame, text="Select:")
MyLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)


MyVar1 = IntVar()
MyVar2 = IntVar()

MyCheckbutton1 = Checkbutton(frame, text="soil", variable=MyVar1, command=forCheckbutton1)
MyCheckbutton1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

MyCheckbutton2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="weather", variable=MyVar2, command=forCheckbutton2)
MyCheckbutton2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)


MyButton1 = Button(frame, text="Submit", width=10, command=forMuButton1)
MyButton1.grid(row=5, columnspan=3)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(rightframe)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )

myList = Listbox(rightframe, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
forCheckbutton1()
forCheckbutton2()

myList.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
scrollbar.config( command = myList.yview )

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "details"? Are you mean file content?

Comment: Yes, the file contents which is in the text format

Comment: exactly, the file contents which is in the text format @Heyran.rs

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `forCheckbutton1()` and `forCheckbutton2()` from mainloop to open dialog box only when the buttons checked. To frame be placed in left side, set `side` to `LEFT`. And for writhing file content in scrollbar, open file in function. Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

win = Tk()

frame = Frame(win)
frame.pack(side=LEFT)

rightframe = Frame(win)
rightframe.pack( side = RIGHT )

win.title("Spatialization of DSSAT model")

w = 800
h = 400

ws = win.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = win.winfo_screenheight()

x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

win.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def forCheckbutton1():
    filename1 = askopenfilename()

    with open(filename1) as f:
        for i in f:
            myList.insert(END, i)

    print(filename1)

def forCheckbutton2():
    filename2 = askopenfilename()

    with open(filename2) as f:
        for i in f:
            myList.insert(END, i)

    print(filename2)

def forMuButton1():
    win.destroy()

def var_states():
    print("soil: %d, \nweather:%d" % (MyVar1.get(), MyVar2.get()))

MyLabel1 = Label(frame, text="Select:")
MyLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)


MyVar1 = IntVar()
MyVar2 = IntVar()

MyCheckbutton1 = Checkbutton(frame, text="soil", variable=MyVar1, command=forCheckbutton1)
MyCheckbutton1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)


MyCheckbutton2 = Checkbutton(frame, text="weather", variable=MyVar2, command=forCheckbutton2)
MyCheckbutton2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)


MyButton1 = Button(frame, text="Submit", width=10, command=forMuButton1)
MyButton1.grid(row=5, columnspan=3)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(rightframe)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y )

myList = Listbox(rightframe, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
myList.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
scrollbar.config( command = myList.yview )

win.mainloop()
```